# Is there a difference between backslash and triple quotes?

Tags: python, line-continuation

I understand that on string assignment that exceeds 1 line you can use either backslash, parenthesis or triple quotes. Is there any practical difference? Which is considered a better coding practice?

For example:

```
STR1 = """Peanut
        butter
        jam"""

STR2 = "Peanut" \
       "butter" \
       "jam"

STR3 = ("Peanut"
        "butter"
        "jam")
```

All of which run perfectly fine, but which one is less prone to future bugs, or is a better practice?

Comment: Try to print them and see for yourself?

Comment: If you print them, you will see that they are not the same. The string expressions in the `STR2` and `STR3` assignments are the same. The expression in `STR3` follows PEP-8 recommendations. The expression in `STR2`  looks very old-fashioned but it is still legal. Trailing backslashes are a nuisance because a space (which you cannot see) after a trailing backslash is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STR1` is, as pointed out [in snatchysquid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63844956/3001761), actually *a different string* to `STR2` and `STR3`. This may not be relevant, depending on the case (e.g. when using regular expressions you can turn on [the verbose flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.X) to ignore the extra whitespace).

Between `STR2` and `STR3`, the [guidance in PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) suggests the latter:

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied
> line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines
> can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in
> parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash
> for line continuation.

With the backslashes, you also can't have comments:

```
>>> STR2 = "Peanut" \
...        "butter" \  # optional
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    "butter" \  # optional
                         ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
>>> STR3 = ("Peanut"
...         "butter"  # optional
...         "jam")
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference indeed since using triple quotes doesn't discount the line feed, `\n`, when pressing `Enter` while the others don't include them, only what's inside the quotes is used.

look at this simple code printing each of them:

```
STR1 = """Peanut
        butter
        jam"""

STR2 = "Peanut" \
       "butter" \
       "jam"

STR3 = ("Peanut"
        "butter"
        "jam")


print(STR1)
print(STR2)
print(STR3)
```

Here's the result:

```
Peanut
        butter
        jam
Peanutbutterjam
Peanutbutterjam
```